# Custom Login page with custom redirects for each user?

Tags: plugins, users, user-roles

I've seen a few different plugins that help with custom redirect upon login, but I think some deal with the initial wordpress login. I have a 'portal' now that displays certain info and I've duplicated it into 4 different modified versions: SuperAdmin, Admin, Billing, GPI.

When the user is on the main site and they click the 'Portal' Nav link, I want that to direct to a custom login page and depending on the role/credentials I want to redirect the user from there to one of the 4 pages. Is there a way that anyone knows of that is best for this type of request? Perhaps a plugin that allows for creation of the login page/form as well as custom redirects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirect-after-login/

Anyway check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127453/redirect-after-login-on-wordpress